# How to covnert only case in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am new to hadoop mapreduce. I want to develop mapreduce code for converting a Text of file in lower case.But with as sequence as earlier in file.That means in actual order of file rather than similar to wordcount data sequence .so can any give me idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the file line by line and  and then emit it as key value **<< LineNumber,UPPERCASEOFLINE >>**,So upper case of each line will become the value for the reducer (A list with only one element).

Now all you have to do is to emit the values (single line for each key) as **key** of the reducer and you can make the reducer **value** as NullWritable.

**LineNumber** in mapper starts at 1 increments once for every line input.
Also override the isSplitable() to return false so as to make one file to be processed entirely by one mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue while converting the given text into upper case through hadoop map reduce program.

follwing is my reducer code snippet

```
public static class UpperCaseReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterator<Text> value,OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,Reporter rporter) throws IOException
        {
            //while(value.hasNext())
            {
                String NULL= new String();
                //System.out.println(value.toString());
                output.collect(value.next(),new Text(""));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my mapper code, I am just reading the input text line and by line as converting the same into upper case and passing the original line as key and converted text as value from my mapper method as an output.